# How to install the latest version of Vim on macOS?

Tags: macos, compile-vim

I'd use Homebrew to install Vim on macOS, with `brew install vim`, but the [Homebrew Formula for Vim](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/vim) seems to install many additional features that I don't need. For example, while I do plan on using Vim to edit Ruby files, I don't plan on using the Ruby interface to Vim. (See `:help ruby`.)

So, when compiling Vim on macOS, what features should I include or leave out (that aren't already included or left out by default), and are there any other custom configuration options I should set?

Interestingly, many people seem to share the settings & plugins they use when running Vim, but not many seem to share the configurations & features they use when compiling Vim.

Comment: AFAIK, the reason people dont share compiled features is because vim is small (comparatively) even with all its features enabled. For most, it doesn’t make sense to.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, spot on. I downloaded Vim source to test a potential new feature, kicked off the build and, before I could get out of my seat to go get a coffee, it had finished :-) Guess I'd gotton used to behemoths like Python or Emacs (or my own software at work).

Answer (score 2):

#### Compile Vim via MacPorts

Macports provides currently a more granular installation approach for vim than homebrew:

It offers the feature variants `tiny`, `small`, `big`, and `huge`.
You can add specifically the interfaces for `ruby`, `perl`, `lua`, `python`.

For all variants see
https://ports.macports.org/port/vim/summary

However, you can add this functionality to the homebrew formula as well (https://docs.brew.sh/Formula-Cookbook#specifying-other-formulae-as-dependencies).  Others might appreciate it.

On the other hand as it has been mentioned: compiling with `huge` by default and adding all interfaces is not really a performance problem. Also you can notice later on that you miss something. You will not run into this situation for the current build and therefore works for everyone.